# Use the fundamental theorem to evaluate the line integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

For part a), I found $||r'(t)|| = \sqrt{18}(t^2+1)$

For part b), I solved $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)*||r'(t)|| dt = \sqrt{2}\frac{24}{5}$

But I am unsure how to solve part c).

I know that the path length of the curve doesn't matter. However, I still don't know what the start and end points of the curve are, so I don't know how to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 3):

A potential function for the field $F$ is $f(x,y,z)=x^3y^2z$.  To use the fundamental theorem evaluate this function at the two endpoints and subtract.

Comment: But how do I know what the two endpoints are?

Comment: $r(1)=(2,3,4)$ and $r(-1)=(-2,3,-4)$